# Google.com instead of google.se?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test google.com outside the US?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-to-test-google-com-outside-the-us)

Whenever I enter google.com in the url it will be converted to google.se.

Is there a way to prohibit that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest Solution I found was the link on your regional google that says go to google.com instead

Comment: I didn't know Google had instant search!

Comment: google instant is a new addition, but its cool

Answer (score 11):

According to Google type:

```
http://www.google.com/ncr
```

That will take you to a region neutral version of Google.

For more details, see the following Google support document:

[Trouble connecting: Google.com automatically takes me to another Google site](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873)

Answer (score 2):

Click "Google.com in English" on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
www.google.com/webhp?hl=en
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on
http://www.google.se/preferences?hl=en
and select the language you want to be your default