# Is there a way to tell Google to speak to me in English, instead of German?

Tags: google-search, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test google.com outside the US?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-to-test-google-com-outside-the-us)

I live in Switzerland, and Google insists on speaking to me in German instead of English. I don't understand German. It's so frustrating. I'm logged in with my account and configured it here http://www.google.com/preferences to work en English every time I log in.

Still, for example, https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount appears in german for me.

BTW, it's extremely frustrated that they don't just give the language I'm requesting, my whole machine works in English and my accept headers clearly list English as my preferred language.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7778/google-com-instead-of-google-se

Answer (score 2):

For most google sites, adding `?hl=en` to the URL always works for me whenever I get redirected to a page with a different language.

Another way to handle it is to add German as the secondary language for your browser.

Comment: Adding German as secondary language causes Google to respect English as my primary language? That would be weirdly awesome.

Comment: That's exactly it. And it _is_ awesome. And it's not only Google, but rather with many other websites too, as far as I'm concerned. I've noticed it on other places as well.