# How to get rid of Google's language detection permanently?

Tags: google, search-engine, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access google.com outside the US?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-can-i-access-google-com-outside-the-us)

Using Chrome 15 on Windows (all tho' I've learned it doesn't matter what browser you use), when using a Google product it automatically either translates or redirects to my native language. If I go google.com, I excpect to get the English version of it - that does not happen, instead I have to click on the bottom of the page on the link "Go to Google MyLanguage" and it still does the same thing after closing and opening the browser.

Hence my question, how to disable (get rid of, for good) Google's language detection? Maybe there's a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL string **hl** sets the interface language for Google Search and many other Google services. You can do same as I did and create different search engines for different languages. When I search for "something" without a keyword, or with the "g" keyword, my browser goes to

> http://www.google.com/search?&tbo=1&prmdo=1&hl=en&q=something

When I search for "something" with the "b" keyword, my browser goes to

> http://www.google.com/search?hl=pt-br&btnG=Search&tbo=1&prmdo=1&q=something

Notice the different **hl** codes for English and Brazilian Portuguese, and the different results they provide. I use Opera, but [Chrome also lets you create new search engines](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95653) just as easily. You just need to do some search with your own language code, access the Chrome search engine options window and set a keyword for it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a link in the lower-right corner. It makes a cookie to keep the setting persistent, unless you log in to your google account, then it will reset.

Another option is to set your browser's language preference to your preferred language.

Comment: Obviously I use a Google account. However Cookie is not the way to get things done permanently, what if I clear cookies or the cookie expires? Either way it will still be a pain.

Comment: Yes. I agree, but the world apparently thinks it wants l10n. File a bug report.